# LazyLoading child-models in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a one to many relation between my objects.

Is it possible to load the childObjects on demand?

For example: I have a Customer and the Customers has Orders. When I load the Customer from the WebService, I dont need the orders, so I only load the Customer. The Orders will only be loaded, when I need them.

Is this possible to realize with ember.js?

Comment: Yes it is, and extremely well suited for it. If you add more information I'll gladly give you a concrete example.  Information such as, are you using Ember yet?  Have you tried to accomplish this yet?  If so, are you using a client side record management framework, such as Ember Data, or Ember Model?  Do you just want to use POJOs?  Are you aware of Ember's Routing?

Comment: Hi, I am using ember model. I was just setting up my models and ran into this question. I have not tried to accomblish this yet. I just need some general information about how to implement such szenarios.
I am also working with routes.